# SUMIFS redundancy

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to make the following formula a bit less redundant, as it may grow out of proportion with some of the modifications i'm looking to perform. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
=minus(SUMIFS(A$2:$A,C$2:$C,K$3)-sumifs(A$2:$A,C$2:$C,K$2),SUMIFS(A$2:$A,C$2:$C,K$5)-sumifs(A$2:$A,C$2:$C,K$4))
```

Please see the [worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IOGfKwLZ6Apng_kmYt0AJh6ztdqHYGJSzAo66zqK0lc/edit#gid=0&vpid=A1)

Comment: You need to share the spreadsheet and explain the issue more.

Comment: Oops, that was a wrong link. Please see - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IOGfKwLZ6Apng_kmYt0AJh6ztdqHYGJSzAo66zqK0lc/edit#gid=0&vpid=A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this standard formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$1000,($B$2:$B$1000=$C$3)+($B$2:$B$1000=$C$4))
-SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$1000,($B$2:$B$1000=$C$2)+($B$2:$B$1000=$C$5))
```

Basically groups the result of the criteria to be added and the ones to be subtracted